# We are able to connect successfully to PPTP VPN (Standard Windows VPN) but once connected, ping through hostnames will not resolve to their IPs

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, windows-server-2012, pptp

We are able to connect successfully to PPTP VPN (Standard Windows VPN) but once connected, ping through hostnames will not resolve to their IPs. For internal, this is working perfectly. This is only happening on remote computers that are joining the network through VPN. We would like to add some DNS A record to save the users from remembering the IPs of the file servers. However, we are facing this problem. Any advise on this guys on how we could fix this issue?

Let me know if you need further details. THANKS!!!!

Comment: What DNS servers are being assigned to the VPN clients? Are they pinging by single-label name or by FQDN?

Comment: Actually, the PPTP VPN server also holds the DNS role so what the clients are getting are the ones configure on the DNS server settings of the server for its LAN adapter. Pinging by single label nor FQDN doesnt work. We always get "Ping request could not find host." result.

Comment: OK, so what DNS servers are the VPN server using? Are they the DNS servers for your AD?

Comment: The VPN server uses its LAN IP (10.1.10.10) as Primary DNS server and (8.8.8.8) as the secondary one. Yeah, I believe 10.1.10.10 is a DNS server of the AD but if I need to confirm, how do I double check this?

Comment: `1.` If your machines are joined to an AD domain then none of them should use external DNS servers (8.8.8.8). `2.` Log onto your domain controller and find it's ip address. That's the ip address that all of your domain joined clients should use for DNS, including your VPN server. This DNS server will then be assigned to the VPN clients and should resolve your name resolution problem.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that our DC is also our VPN server and DNS server. So right now this DC/DNS/VPN server of ours has these DNS settings.
Primary DNS: 10.1.10.10 (own IP of the DC/DNS/VPN server)
Alternate DNS: 8.8.8.8 (Because we only have 1 DNS server)

These DNS servers are being assigned to the VPN clients as we have checked. However, even if the clients do, they cant still ping the internal resources by HOSTNAME  or FQDN which is what we wanted for them to use instead of IPs. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Yes, get rid of 8.8.8.8. Then make sure that every domain client only has 10.1.10.10 for primary DNS. If you only have one DNS server for AD (10.1.10.10) then that's all you should configure. Domain clients (including the DC) should only use the AD DNS servers for DNS and NEVER use external DNS servers. Then verify that all hosts have registered in DNS. Then run nslookup from a VPN client and run some lookups for internal names.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I'll try this after hours and get back here for the results!

Comment: Tried removing the 8.8.8.8 alternate DNS but sadly it didn't work. Do you have any other ideas how to solve or what is causing this issue? Thanks!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still unable to resolve the issue. Any ideas guys? Thanks!